# How to use computer IP address when making request to lambda running offline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

Hi I am trying to access my lambda using my computer's local IP address but am repeatedly getting a `Connection refused` error.

However if I use:

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/my-path`

the endpoint works fine.

Would anyone have any suggestions for what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add the following in my `serverless.yml`:

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    host: '0.0.0.0'
```